# What is a deleted segment in linux pmap output?

Tags: linux, pmap

Here are the first few lines of output from pmap on a process, running on CentOS 5.2:

```
Address   Kbytes     RSS    Anon  Locked Mode   Mapping
00101000    1268       -       -       - r-x--  libc-2.5.so
0023e000       8       -       -       - r----  libc-2.5.so
00240000       4       -       -       - rw---  libc-2.5.so
00241000      12       -       -       - rw---    [ anon ]
00244000      36       -       -       - r-x--  threads.so (deleted)
0024d000       4       -       -       - rw---  threads.so (deleted)
0024e000      20       -       -       - r-x--  Socket.so (deleted)
00253000       4       -       -       - rw---  Socket.so (deleted)
[...]
```

What does "(deleted)" mean on the shared library mappings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That means that the file in question has been deleted. Its link count in the filesystem has gone to 0. The file will stay around until the last in-kernel reference to it has been closed, then it will be removed from the disk.

You will often see this when a program has continued running while the packaging system has installed new updates. The old libraries have been removed and new libraries installed.